# I'm looking for a YA superhero book series

Tags: story-identification, books, super-hero

This YA superhero book series (trilogy?) is kinda like *Hero Academia* (I think). It was recommended on a comment a video I saw about 'Superhero Tropes'. I didn't get chance to read it, but it was not available there.

I forget the title, but it wasn't from Marvel or DC. It's basically on it own.

Comment: I the thing is i actually posted after searching the comments section some have 1k and i don't to search that and there three of them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There must be dozens, maybe hundreds, of young adult superhero fantasies, and limiting it to superhero academies doesn't narrow the field much. But as it happens one springs to mind that I read recently and thoroughly enjoyed, so I'll post it as an answer if only to give others a chance to share my enjoyment in the series i.e. the [Super Powered series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/115317-super-powereds) by Drew Hayes:

> Knowledge is power. That would be the motto of Lander University, had it not been snatched up and used to death by others long before the school was founded. For while Lander offers a full range of courses to nearly all students, it also offers a small number of specialty classes to a very select few. Lander is home to the Hero Certification Program, a curriculum designed to develop student with superhuman capabilities, commonly known as Supers, into official Heroes.
>
> Five of this year’s freshmen are extra special. They have a secret aside from their abilities, one that they must guard from even their classmates. Because for every one person in the world with abilities they can control, there are three who lack such skill. These lesser super beings, Powereds as they are called, have always been treated as burdens and second class citizens. Though there has been ample research in the area, no one has ever succeeded in turning a Powered into a regular human, let alone a Super.
>
> That is, until now…

This was originally a serial published on the web and Hayes eventually converted it to a series of four books. It is a superhero series, it is based around a university, it is young adult, but most of all it is excellent entertainment.